# matplotlib annotation overlapping y_tick labels on plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried a number of different things to fix my chart, from zorder on the plots to plt.rcParams.

I feel that this is such a simple problem but I just dont know where I have gone wrong. As you can see the bottom annotation in cyan blue is unreadable and mashed with the y label.

Ideally, the annotation sits over the y label to a point where text inside annotation is readable.

If possible just for the annotation to sit on top and still overlay the y label..something like this

[image]
[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
ax = df.plot(x=df.columns[0], y=df.columns[1], legend=False, zorder=0, linewidth=1)
y1 =df.loc[:, df.columns[2]].tail(1)
y2= df.loc[:, df.columns[1]].tail(1)


colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]
print(colors)
for var in (y1, y2):
    plt.annotate('%0.2f' % var.max(), xy=(1, var.max()), zorder=1, xytext=(8, 0), 
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), 
                 textcoords='offset points', 
                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc=colors[0], ec=colors[0],))

ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot(x=df.columns[0], y=df.columns[2], ax=ax2, legend=False, color='#fa8174', zorder=0,linewidth=1)


ax.figure.legend(prop=subtitle_font)
ax.grid(True, color="white",alpha=0.2)

pack = [df.columns[1], df.columns[2], freq[0]]
plt.text(0.01, 0.95,'{0} v {1} - ({2})'.format(df.columns[1], df.columns[2], freq[0]),
     horizontalalignment='left',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform = ax.transAxes,
     zorder=10,
     fontproperties=subtitle_font)

ax.text(0.01,0.02,"Sources: FRED, Quandl, @Paul92s",
    color="white",fontsize=10, 
    horizontalalignment='left', 
    transform = ax.transAxes, 
     verticalalignment='center', 
     zorder=20, 
     fontproperties=subtitle_font)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator((4,7,10)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter()) # matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%m")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha="center", zorder=-1)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0, zorder=-1)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0, zorder=-1)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(14,7)
ax.set_xlabel('Data as of; {0}'.format(df['Date'].max().strftime("%B %d, %Y")), fontproperties=subtitle_font)


y1 =df.loc[:, df.columns[2]].tail(1)
y2= df.loc[:, df.columns[1]].tail(1)

for var in (y1, y2):
    plt.annotate('%0.2f' % var.max(), xy=(1, var.max()), zorder=1,xytext=(8, 0), 
                 xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), 
                 textcoords='offset points', 
                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="#fa8174", ec="#fa8174"))


plt.title('{0}'.format("FRED Velocity of M2 Money Stock v Trade Weighted U.S. Dollar Index: Broad"),fontproperties=heading_font)
ax.texts.append(ax.texts.pop())
ax.set_facecolor('#181818')
ax.figure.set_facecolor('#181818')
plt.rcParams['axes.axisbelow'] = True
```

Comment: What outcome do you want when the two nearly match?

Comment: @MadPhysicist if possible just for the annotation to sit on top and still overlay the y label, in my head just an ordering issue. But zorder doesn't seem to be working. 
Similar to this [link]https://imgur.com/BGwgtQe

Comment: Add to your question please. And images, not galleries

Answer (score 0):

I don't figure out why `zorder` doesn't work, but you can directly set the label style of tick labels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(rand(100), '^', color='r')

for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='orange'))

ax1 = ax.twinx()

ax1.plot(rand(100), 'o', color='b')

index_to_add_bbox = [2, 4]
ax1_labels = ax1.get_yticklabels()

for i in index_to_add_bbox:
    ax1_labels[i].set_bbox(dict(boxstyle='Circle', facecolor='orange'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as I have learned the order of the axis matters. So the solution is to plot the labels on the 2nd axis.