# How to integrate subcharts in one matplotlib axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

Looking at the output of [backtrader](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader), I can see that there seems to be a feature in matplotlib to integrate several subcharts in a single plot:

[image: see also https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/plotting/ respectively https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/01-sample-code.png]
(see also https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/plotting/ )

The screenshot shows one figure - apparently without any matplotlib subplots - that has three subcharts (`broker`, `trades`, `price data`).

I know how to create subplots with matplotlib - but this is not what I am looking for.

I would like to know how one can create in one axes (is this the right matplotlib term?) several subcharts that share the same x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what the picture shows by defining the `height_ratios` among subplots.

> several subcharts that shares the same x axis.

You can refer to [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) about `sharex` and `sharey`

> When subplots have a shared x-axis along a column, only the x tick
> labels of the bottom subplot are created.
>
> Similarly, when subplots have a shared y-axis along a row, only the y tick labels of the first column subplot are created.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex='col',
                        gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1], 'height_ratios': [2, 2, 10],
                        'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

# avoid overlay
axs[1].set_yticks([0, 0.5, 1])
axs[1].set_yticklabels(["", "0.5", ""])

   
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you are interested in how to annotate y labels, you can look at my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350198/10315163).

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent library for visualization of stocks, etc. Originally included in matplotlib, but now an independent library, I'll give a simplified answer to the [example](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb) on Github. The formula can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/).

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

idf = pd.read_csv('data/SPY_20110701_20120630_Bollinger.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df = idf.loc['2011-07-01':'2011-12-30',:]

mpf.plot(df, volume=True, tight_layout=True, figscale=0.75, style='checkers')
```

[image]